# AngularFire Seed directive "isAdmin" or "showAdmin"

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularjs-service, angularfire, angular-ui-router

I am using AngularFire Seed project. I want to show different views for admins and normal registered users. AngularFire Seed project has built-in directive called "ngShowAuth" which you can find here: [simpleLoginTools](https://gist.github.com/katowulf/7328023). This directive is used to show different views for registered and unregistered user. same way i want to show different views for admins and users.

I StumbledUpon it and found this [stackoverflow resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23420106/angular-firebase-angularfire-seed-directive-showadmin) . i tried to implement it and it doesn't work. i want to fire this service as soon as user.uid becomes available.

Preferably i just want to execute the service and once the isAdmin is set to true or false, i want to filter the views in the states routes.

here is the service and the directive:

```js
'use strict';

angular.module('bpmWaitForAdmin', [])

    .service('bpmWaitForAdmin', function ($rootScope, syncData, waitForAuth) {
        return {
            init: function (auth) {
                $rootScope.$on('$firebaseSimpleLogin:login', function (e, user) {
                    var admins = syncData('admins');

                    admins.$on("loaded", function () {
                        if (user.uid in admins) {
                            $rootScope.$broadcast('bpmWaitForAdmin:true');
                        }

                        else {
                            $rootScope.$broadcast('bpmWaitForAdmin:false');
                        }
                    });
                });

                $rootScope.$on('$firebaseSimpleLogin:logout', function () {
                    $rootScope.$broadcast('bpmWaitForAdmin:false');
                });
            }
        };
    })

    .directive('bpmShowAdmin', function ($rootScope, $timeout) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            compile: function (element, attributes) {
                element.addClass('hide');

                $rootScope.$on("bpmWaitForAdmin:true", function () {
                    $timeout(function () {
                        element.removeClass('hide');
                    });
                });

                $rootScope.$on("bpmWaitForAdmin:false", function () {
                    $timeout(function () {
                        element.addClass('hide');
                    });
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: are the `bpmWaitForAdmin` events being fired and picked up in the directive? if so what does the `hide` class do? in angular the class name is `ng-hide`

Comment: Nope it doesn't work. Yes but just adding 'hide' class will work without any problem. Forget about directive i just want to know to to get this service running since the inbuilt service 'waitForAuth' written in 'simpleLoginTools' module is not injected or called by any controller function, yet that service is working fine.

Comment: "it doesn't work" will, in every case and for all ages, be insufficient to help troubleshoot any technical problem. Please include version info, the error received, and all code needed to reproduce those conditions. Please see [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Cross-posted here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-angular/5nSCooLa1vc